# pug : TypeError: View is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to make a website using NodeJS with express and pug for templates.
I integrated Pug using the express docs, but I keep getting `TypeError: View is not a constructor` on the render function. I really looked, but the only people who had this problem got it with other templates, and were not doing it has simple.
So at the end I did it like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

server.set('views', './views');
server.set('view engine', 'pug');

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('example', {title: "code", message: "message"});
});

require('./settings')(server);  console.log('Settings initialized');

server.listen(server.settings.port);
console.log('Server listening on port', server.settings.port);
```

And in views/ the template looks like :

```
html
  head
    title = title
  body
    h1 = message
```

In package.json, I imported it like : `"pug": "^2.0.0-rc.1"`

Thank you for your tips ! And have a nice day.

-- EDIT --
So I made a little experiment by uninstalling pug ... I have the same result, so I guess I didn't install or parametrized well pug.
-- EDIT --
Made some other tests and it turns out without the require it works well. But I don't see why, and I need to import external files.

Comment: For starters, you should remove the space between `title` and the equals-sign (same for the heading) - so `title=`, not `title =`. This most likely won't fix the issue you're facing, but with the space in-between, the code does not work the way you expect it to (it would have `= title` as the title of the page, instead of the actual value of the `title` variable).

Comment: Thank you @gandreadis I corrected it.

Comment: This error is being caused by code/config that you haven't pasted here, as it's going to be thrown by a variable/setting named View or view.  You should uninstall and reinstall using `express --view=pug` and consider deleting or editing this question.

Comment: Did you try to move the `require('./settings')(server);` to the top? Also use another syntax for the require like `const settings = require('./settings');`?

Answer (score 0):

This could be happen for various reason one of the most frequent is that there is a typo in the way you use pug in your index.js or where the object is instanced.

After made sure to have installed it locally( check your package.json) and to have created a root a folder called "views", and in there same file that you use in your rooter, then to be sure to use the sintax:

```
server.set('view engine', 'pug');
server.set('views','./views');// default, but if you specify don't make mistake on this
```

In your case I believe it is the order that caused this error.

Another note, useful is that the pug sintax, is required that "tags" are followed without space by "=", like:

```
html 
   head 
      title= title
   body
      h1= message
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because of a typo in `views`

```
server.set('view', './views');
server.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

I fixed it by putting an `s` to views

```
server.set('views', './views');
```

Answer (score 0):

(this discussion assumes app is express: `var app = express();`)

You're getting this error because you're stepping on `app.settings`, which contains a `view` property.

I understand the appeal of wanting to call `app.settings`, so you can use `app.settings.custom` instead, and it won't cause a clash:

settings.ts

```
module.exports = {
    port: 3000
}
```

app.ts

```
  // settings
  app.settings.custom = require('./settings')

  ...

  var server = await app.listen(app.settings.custom.port, async () => {
    var address = server.address()
    console.log(`app.js - server started at ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} in ${app.environment} - http://${address.address}:${address.port}`)
  })
```

If you don't like `.custom`, you can use `Object.assign(app.settings, mySettings)`, just make sure no property values clash.